# How to render part of the texture inside the quad in opengl es using shaders

Tags: c++, c, opengl-es, glsl

I am trying to render some part of the texture inside my quad using the shader and an object file (.pod) which is nothing but container format of holding the vertices, normals and UVs.

so, just imagine i made a simple quad using 3ds max and export it as .pod and load into my scene from world to MVP . it has UVs as `(0,0)(1,0)(0,1)(1,1)` .. now I have a texture(.pvr) of `1024x128` pixels. I have sent all the data from cpp to vertex shader using appropriate buffers and everything is working fine.

Now question is, I want to render only some of the texture, lets say, starting from `200,30(left,bottom)` pixels to `500,100(width,height)`.

How can I achieve the above using the vertex shader. I have written some logic in vertex shader, which acc to me is working for `(0,0)` coordinates, but how can I define height, width as there is only one vec2 variable. Below is the logic in vertex shader...

```
varying mediump vec2   TexCoord;
attribute mediump vec2  inTexCoord;

TexCoord.x = inTexCoord.x * (1024.0/(1024.0-200.0))-(200.0/1024.0);
TexCoord.y = inTexCoord.y * (128.0/(128.0-30.0))-(30.0/128.0);
```

same logic and values are working for all the UVs, Dont know how to mention height, width in it. and above code is doing some trick but not what I am expecting. it is repeating the texture inside the quad.
 Instead I want to render only `(200,30,500,100)(l,b,w,h)` part of the texture and that too inside the quad showing black boundary on the side of the quad from `0-127` pixels and `0-30` pixels from left and bottom respectively and black border from `629th` pixel to `1024` from right .

I am trying to make A video wall project where TVs will be rotated in diff diff angles.

Comment: Sounds like you're trying to letterbox or something in the shader.  You can do it but personally I'd change the geometry you're mapping onto to suit, i.e. change the aspect of the rectangle area representing the screen, rather than fiddling about in the shaders.

Comment: Your calculation looks wrong. I'm not sure where you got this formula from.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The correct calculation from mapping frmo [0, 1] to a start (s) and a length (l) is

```
x_mapped = x * l + s
```

When looking at your special problem, you should be using:

```
TexCoord.x = inTexCoord.x * (width/1024.0)  + (left/1024.0);
TexCoord.y = inTexCoord.y * (height/1024.0) + (bottom/1024.0);
```

Comment: I believe the only problem with this is if we were doing it from the top wouldn't it be `TexCoord.y = inTexCoord.y * (height/1024.0) - (top/1024.0);`? as the BL corner of OpenGL coordinates is 0,0? or `TexCoord.y = inTexCoord.y * (height/1024.0) + ((top+height)/1024.0);`

Comment: @Eddge: It should have been "bottom" instead of "top" (as it was asked for in the question). Non of your two formulas look correct to me, here two counter examples: The first one produces for `y=0` a value of `-(top/1024)` which is negative. Second one for `y=1, top=512, height=512` (bottom half), `result=1.5`. For valid parameter combination inside the texture, the result always has to be between [0, 1].

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply and solutions @BDL. It is working, but partially for me. What I am trying is to render that part of the texture at the location in the quad only.
attaching an image where you can see full texture and after making changes, it become tiled texture. 

[ http://imgur.com/a/JkJ4P ]

` TexCoord.x = inTexCoord.x * (1024.0/1024.0)+(500.0/1024.0);
   TexCoord.y = inTexCoord.y * (128.0/128.0)+(64.0/128.0); `

Comment: Sorry for my formatting in the comment.. i use stackoverflow very less for asking. but in image you can see, the actual part which i want to see is coming from left to the center of the quad and rest is tiling. i am trying to render that part on the right top part of the quad only and rest as black.. Is there anything to do with glTexparameteri call.. as i am not using that call at all..

Comment: @SIM: Ah, then I missread your question. What you want is not possible in a vertex shader. It is possible with an if in the fragment shader, but very inefficient. Better solution: Adjust the rectangle to be where you need it to be.

Comment: @BDL: Can you please tell me how to that in the fragment shader ... actually the problem is, i am trying to do this without any transformation on quad. I have already scaled and translated all the rectangles enough to show in all the TV's. now the problem is coming, when tv's are rotated to some angles, then it should not look like stretched in one Tv and not in another.. here No of TV = No of android Devices.
below is what i am trying to achieve
(http://www.videowall.in/assets/media/portfolio/asymmetric-display.jpg )

Comment: @BDL You're right, that's what I get for running it through my head after just waking up.

Answer (score 0):

So,I was trying more on this to work, either efficient or inefficient way, below is what I have implemented in the fragment shader and seems like working out for me..please check once n let me know any optimization can be made on this. Below code will draw only the part of the texture i want to see in screen at the same place in the quad.

```
const float MAX_WIDTH = 1280.0;
const float MAX_HEIGHT = 720.0;

const float LEFT = 00.0;
const float TOP = 00.0;
const float WIDTH = 500.0;
const float HEIGHT = 500.0;

void main()
{
    vec2 p = TexCoord;
    float xx,xw,yy,yh,b;

    xx = (LEFT/MAX_WIDTH);
    xw = ((LEFT + WIDTH)/MAX_WIDTH);
    yy = (TOP/MAX_HEIGHT);
    yh = ((TOP + HEIGHT)/MAX_HEIGHT);

    if((p.x > xx) && (p.x < xw) && (p.y > yy) && (p.y < yh))
            b = 1.0;
    else
            b = 0.0;
    gl_FragColor = vec4((texture2D(sTexture, TexCoord).rgb),texture2D(sTexture,TexCoord).a * b);

}
```

This below part in vertex shader will load only the part of texture which i want to see but covering the whole quad.

```
    TexCoord.x = inTexCoord.x * (WIDTH/MAX_WIDTH)+(LEFT/MAX_WIDTH);
    TexCoord.y = inTexCoord.y * (HEIGHT/MAX_HEIGHT)+(TOP/MAX_HEIGHT);
```

Thanks for solving this.. @BDL